# Problems with query function laravel

Tags: database, laravel, function

I would like to load the user, which has the appropriate url in the table invites stored. Unfortunately, I do not get the query written. How can I switch to the table "invites" and still load the right user to the page?

Relation:

One to one

Route

```
 Route::get('/invite/{url}', 'Auth\RegisterController@show')->name('invite.show');
```

Table invites:

```
Schema::create('invites', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->text('greeting')->nullable();
            $table->string('url')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

function

```
public function show($url)
{
    $user = User::where(function ($query) use ($url) {
        $query->where('invites.url', '=', $url);
    })->first();

    return view('invite_user', compact('user'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$user = User::whereHas('invites', function($query) use($url) {
    $query->where('url', $url);
})->first();
```

Make sure that you have the `invites` relationship function in your `User` model like so:

```
public function invites() {
    return $this->hasMany(Invite::class, 'user_id');
}
```